# Problems to use sms Phonegap plugin

Tags: ios, plugins, cordova, sms

When using the SMS Composer on IOS 6.1, the plugin works fine when call using the instruction provided in the example:

```
cordova.exec(null,null, 'SMSComposer','showSMSComposer',[args]);
```

When using the following instruction in the Usage Notes to pass a number and body text, the plugin does not load:

```
window.plugins.smsComposer.showSMSComposer('9999999999', 'hello');
```

Can anyone please shed some light on this for me?

Comment: Do you get an error when it "does not load"?  What does "does not load" mean?

Comment: dear chris I was trying to send sms without user interaction. Checking the apple manual I see that is impossible.

Answer (score 0):

iOS Does not allow sending SMS without presenting UI.
http://blog.mugunthkumar.com/coding/iphone-tutorial-how-to-send-in-app-sms/